# How do i change time.monotonic to epoch time or normal time

Tags: python, time, timestamp, epoch

How would i change `time.monotonic()` to epoch time or normal time? I tried this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import *

current_time = monotonic()

print(datetime.fromtimestamp(current_time))
```

But the output is:

```
1970-01-06 03:43:25.687000
```

I think its reading epoch time instead of monotonic time so how can i change monotonic time to epoch time or normal time.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.monotonic), the absolute value of the monotonic clock is undefined i.e. it doesn't make much sense by itself.

If you check the values returned by `monotonic`, they're not timestamps:

```
>>> from time import monotonic
>>> t = monotonic()
>>> t
32.919858958
>>> t
32.919858958
>>> t = monotonic()
>>> t
37.346707458
```

The only guarantee it makes is that successive calls to `monotonic()` return increasing values. So only the difference between these values are meaningful as time deltas.